# Getting Instagram API work again

Tags: api, permissions, instagram, permission-denied, platform

I have worked on a Platform that uses Instagram API. We integrated analytics to measure hashtags# (amount of followers, likes, reactions).

But thanks to the new Instagram Policy the platform does not work anymore.

We now we need to get permission but Instagram is declining our requests for: public_content 
follower_list

We need a solution for this problem does anyone had this problem before or can help us?